# copy and paste files from windows

Tags: 14.04

Hey I just dual boot my pc with windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04.my question is how can I copy my files from windows and paste them in Ubuntu with the help of command only?

Comment: It depends on where your Windows partitions are mount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Find your Windows partitions (based on size) you want to copy** aka `/dev` name :

   - use`sudo fdisk -l`

[image]

On the picture you can see NTFS partitions under ID 7.

2. **Check what devices you have mounted**:

   - use `mount | grep /dev`
3. **If your `/dev/windows-partition` won't be listed, we need to mount it**

   - `cd /mnt` (will change directory to standard mounting dir)
   - `sudo mkdir Windows` (will create folder named Windows, where you NTFS partition will be mounted)
   - `sudo mount -t auto -v /dev/sdX /mnt/Windows` (where sdX is path/name of your Windows partition)
4. **To check if everything is mounted correctly**:

   - `cd Windows | ls -la` - you should see your Windows drive structure
5. **Copy your Windows files to Ubuntu partition**

   - `mkdir /home/user/Windowsfiles` (will create Windowsfiles folder in your home directory)
   - To copy use: `rsync -av --progress /mnt/Windows /home/user/Windowsfiles` **OR** `cp -avr /mnt/Windows /home/user/Windowsfiles`

*This will copy your whole let's say `D: drive` to `/home/user/Windowsfiles`*

*Modify mount directory name and target directory path (and name) to your liking.*

**If you need clarification, let me know.**